# COMException thrown when executing DLL method from separate thread in .NET 4.5.2

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, dll, comexception

I have a .NET service that references `XpdfPrint.dll` that is used for printing. The print method of XpdfPrint library is executed in separate thread that looks like this:

```
Thread xPdfPrintThread = new Thread(() => 
{
    try
    {
        xPDF.printPDF4();
    }
    catch (COMException e)
    {
        // check for the specific errorcode and log an error
    }
 });
```

This worked good and well until I changed target framework from .NET 3.5 to .NET 4.5.2. Now, the call to `printPDF4()` is failing with:

```
Exception: Error HRESULT E_FAIL has returned from a call to a COM component.
```

If I take the call out of the thread and execute it, it completes fine. Any idea on why upgrading .NET to 4.5.2 would break this?

Update:
Instantiating the COM object within the thread instead of outside the thread resolves the issue. I still have no clue why this behaves differently in .NET 4.5.2.

Comment: Which thread creates the COM object?

Comment: @MichaelGunter the thread that starts xPdfPrintThread. In other words xPDF object in example above is instantiated outside the thread that executes printPDF4().

Comment: Try manually setting the apartment state in the main thread and/or the background thread.

Comment: I wonder whether it's necessary to call CoInitialize/CoInitializeEx explicitly when it's a .NET service. Don't think so, but perhaps worth investigating.

Comment: @MichaelGunter manually setting the apartment state results in System.AccessViolationException.

Comment: Inside which method does that exception occur?

Comment: @MichaelGunter Sorry I didn't mention that. It's failing at the same method call. xPDF.printPDF4();. Also, instantiating the COM object within the thread  instead of outside the thread resolves the issue.

Comment: Sounds like a marshaling issue. I have been googling to find anything that may be different between the two versions of .NET and haven't found anything. :(

Comment: @MichaelGunter I couldn't find anything either.